# Is there going to be version of spring-data-aerospike for Spring Boot 2?

Tags: aerospike

We are using Spring Boot 2 and tried to use Aerospike with it. 
Spring Data repositories are really nice, and spring-data-aerospike implements them for seamless working with Aerospike.
It's a pity however, it doesn't run with Spring Boot 2, even though the project itself is live.
I wonder what could be a time frame for a version compatible with Spring Boot 2?

Comment: I think your question should be addressed to Spring developers 
via https://spring.io/questions or http://forum.spring.io/

Comment: Latest release compatible with Spring Boot 2: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aerospike/spring-data-aerospike/2.0.1.RELEASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try out [this branch](https://github.com/aerospike/spring-data-aerospike/tree/spring-data-2.0) of the aerospike spring data project. It is a preview of the spring data 2.0 changes.

Comment: Thanks **a lot**! I compiled it and tested and it works at least for my simple case of the Repository like

`
public interface ProductRepository extends AerospikeRepository<Product, Integer> {
    Product findOneByDescription(String description);
}
`